# Trying to parse some json but i am getting a key error - Django

Tags: python, json, django

I have a request that I am sending to an API and i am getting a json format response. I want to grab items from the response that is being sent back but not getting anything out of it. I am getting an error with the keys that I am putting in to grab.

From the response below, I want to grab values for specific keys within the response and save them in variables to eventually save them within my database.

Here is the code that I have:

```
def createUserSynapse(request):
    argss = {
        'email': 'hello@synapsepay.com',
        'phone_number': '555-555-5555',
        'legal_name': 'Hello McHello',
        'note': ':)',  # optional
        'supp_id': '123abc',  # optional
        'is_business': True,
        'cip_tag': 1
    }
    user = SynapseUser.create(clients, **argss)
    print(user.json)
    response = json.loads(user)
    if response:
        _id = response['_id']
        name = response.client['name']
        link = response._links.self['href']
        cip = response.extra['cip_tag']
        supp = response.extra['supp_id']
        print(name)
        print(_id)
        print(link)
        print(cip)
        print(supp)
```

here is a sample of the reply:

```
{  
   '_id':'..4e57',
   '_links':{  
      'self':{  
         'href':'https://uat-api.synapsefi.com/v3.1/users/..54e57'
      }
   },
   'client':{  
      'id':'..26a34',
      'name':'Charlie Brown LLC'
   },
   'doc_status':{  
      'physical_doc':'MISSING|INVALID',
      'virtual_doc':'MISSING|INVALID'
   },
   'documents':[  

   ],
   'emails':[  

   ],
   'extra':{  
      'cip_tag':1,
      'date_joined':1504774195147,
      'extra_security':False,
      'is_business':True,
      'last_updated':1504774195147,
      'public_note':None,
      'supp_id':'123abc'
   },
   'is_hidden':False,
   'legal_names':[  
      'Hello McHello'
   ],
   'logins':[  
      {  
         'email':'hello@synapsepay.com',
         'scope':'READ_AND_WRITE'
      }
   ],
   'permission':'UNVERIFIED',
   'phone_numbers':[  
      '555-555-5555'
   ],
   'photos':[  

   ],
   'refresh_token':'refresh_..G8LPqF6'
}
```

And here is the error that I am getting from the browser:

```
TypeError at /setup_profile/
the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'User'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/setup_profile/
Django Version: 1.8.6
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'User'
```

** UPDATE **

the following is the response when i just print user:

```
<class 'synapse_pay_rest.models.users.user.User'>({'client': <class 'synapse_pay_rest.client.Client'>(base_url=https://uat-api.synapsefi.com/v3.1), 'json': {'_id': '..920e6', '_links': {'self': {'href': 'https://uat-api.synapsefi.com/v3.1/users/..920e6'}}, 'client': {'id': '..026a34', 'name': 'Charlie Brown LLC'}, 'doc_status': {'physical_doc': 'MISSING|INVALID', 'virtual_doc': 'MISSING|INVALID'}, 'documents': [], 'emails': [], 'extra': {'cip_tag': 1, 'date_joined': 1505093840940, 'extra_security': False, 'is_business': True, 'last_updated': 1505093840940, 'public_note': None, 'supp_id': '123abc'}, 'is_hidden': False, 'legal_names': ['Hello McHello'], 'logins': [{'email': 'hello@synapsepay.com', 'scope': 'READ_AND_WRITE'}], 'permission': 'UNVERIFIED', 'phone_numbers': ['555-555-5555'], 'photos': [], 'refresh_token': 'refresh_..cYbeIrNA3P'}, 'id': '..920e6', 'refresh_token': 'refresh_..eIrNA3P', 'logins': [{'email': 'hello@synapsepay.com', 'scope': 'READ_AND_WRITE'}], 'phone_numbers': ['555-555-5555'], 'legal_names': ['Hello McHello'], 'permission': 'UNVERIFIED', 'note': None, 'supp_id': '123abc', 'is_business': True, 'cip_tag': 1, 'base_documents': 0, 'oauth_key': 'oauth_..dQZUJ', 'expires_in': '7200'})
```

Here is what comes from the type user and type user.json:

type(user) returns

```
<class 'synapse_pay_rest.models.users.user.User'>
```

type(user.json)

```
<class 'dict'>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is coming from the json loads line

```
response = json.loads(user)
```

This is because json.loads expects a string object that can be converted to a json dictionary, but it is being passed a `user` object, and consequently throwing a TypeError.

In your case, since the type of user.json is a dictionary, we can simply replace the response line with this:

```
response = user.json
```

Comment: So how can i change that or fix that so that my code returns a string that can be converted @arjun27.... why is a user object being returned... how do i know if it is returning json or a user object...

Comment: Please share output of: type(user) and type(user.json). You can use the type function in python to find out the type of the object

Comment: i am going to add the response why i take the .json out of the print user in the original post... it says json:.. I will also add the type user and type user.json in the original post.... just give me a minute @arjun27

Comment: Just use: response = user.json

Comment: It worked. can you make it an answer to the question so i upvote it and people know it is how to do it when they look on here. or you can just append it to your existing answers

Comment: thank you. i upvoted it and accepted it as an answer